# c++: for loop being skipped

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers

Working with win32 and am trying to populate a vector in accordance to a combo box.
Naturally I have to clear out the old data from the vector, but when doing so the vector->clear(); function causes the remaining code in the switch statement to be skipped.

```
case CMB_DATA1:
    mDataSet1Yaxis->clear();

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < mDataFile.mAllData.size(); i++)
    {
        mDataSet1Yaxis->push_back(mDataFile.mAllData[i][SendMessage(mUI->hDataSet1, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0)]);
    }
    cout << "iterated...";
    break;
```

I'm not sure, but I guess this has something to do with mUI->hDataSet1 being said to be unused?
What does this mean and how can I fix it?

---

edit 1:
variable declarations

```
OpenDataFile mDataFile = OpenDataFile();
vector<vector<SooberCell>> mAllData;

vector<SooberCell>* mDataSet1Yaxis;
```

---

edit 2:
I think the biggest issue here is stemming from mDataSet1Yaxis

Comment: what is the definition for clear() method? Please post that.

Comment: start iteration from 0?

Comment: Run in a debugger, set a breakpoint in this code, check what `mDataFile.mAllData.size()` returns.

Comment: chnossos: when debugging it (even with break points spammed across it all, none of them trigger) and stepping through the code is jumped over.
neska: the 0 item in the array isn't part of the data, hence it is skipped
hagubear: its standard vector clear, check it out on msdn
P0W: mDataFile should be a vector of vector of my own class.
joachimPileborg: will do

Comment: @BrandonWhite step into clear

Comment: Please declarations of these variables.

Comment: @BrandonWhite Random ideas: Perhaps an exception is being thrown out of `clear()` and it's getting caught somewhere else? Look at the disassembly to see if the compiler is even emitting code for the `for` loop? (An optimization might have removed the loop completely, either erroneously or because the compiler knows something you don't.)

Comment: Please pay attention to the answer of @Neska, I'm absolutely sure that this is the issue here :) (most probably you will not find anything in the `clear()` function documentation)

Comment: Good point; i assumed that the loop was intended to do something (ie size >1). But cout isn't being executed either, unless the question is inaccurately written, suggesting undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BrandonWhite - `the 0 item in the array isn't part of the data,` Faking 1-based arrays in C++ is begging for an off-by-one error somewhere.

Comment: the loop is for a data set of some 16,000+ values, the 1st of which (array 0) is the name of the data.

Comment: @BrandonWhite So...is it hitting the cout line or not?

Comment: Might it be that `mDataSet1Yaxis` which is a pointer to a vector is not initialized at all?

Comment: @joachimPileborg the exact size of mDataFile.mAllData.size() is 16282

Comment: @BrandonWhite - `the 1st of which (array 0) is the name of the data.`  Then you would have been better off using `std::map<std::string, std::vector<T>>`.  Then you would not have to do these 1-based array tricks.

Comment: Is `mDataSet1Yaxis` even initialised or is it left as a dangling pointer?

Comment: @BrandonWhite Please answer the question of how you initialize `mDataSet1Yaxis` in your code :)

Comment: @TommyA i think you may be onto an embarrassing error there...
a lot of this came of having changed everything to pointers from variables in order to make it more efficient.

Comment: @BrandonWhite - Did you measure that it would be more efficient to use pointers, or was it just a guess?  If you haven't profiled your code, why change something that worked to something that has a much greater chance of failing?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was told that passing by pointer instead of passing by reference was more memory efficient by a lecturer.

Comment: @BrandonWhite - Your lecturer needs a lecturer.  You gain basically nothing passing an address as opposed to passing a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have created a pointer to a vector but not really instantiated the vector, so your pointer is dangling, and as such what you experience is undefined behaviour.

Perhaps your line:

```
vector<SooberCell>* mDataSet1Yaxis;
```

Should be changed to:

```
vector<SooberCell>* mDataSet1Yaxis = new vector<SooberCell>();
```

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie true and with no usage of the variable it can be removed :) the example is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out I had forgotten to initialize `mDataSet1Yaxis` and thus nothing was happening within the for loop...

Comment: No, not nothing; undefined behaviour; even the cout outside the loop wasn't being executed.